# How can I troubleshoot a Nikon D5000 self timer that isn't working?

Tags: troubleshooting, nikon-d5000, self-timer

I have a Nikon D5000 and the self timer stopped working.  Any ideas on how to troubleshoot and get it to work again?

Comment: Check page 65 [in the manual](https://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D5000_en.pdf) to make sure you haven't skipped a step... The release modes are software driven so I'm not sure how that would stop working on its own.

Comment: Are there any other symptoms, or error messages? Does it give any indication it won't work before you press the shutter button? Does the menu allow you select the self timer?